# Few images on the same line

Tags: html, css

I need to images will be on the same line. How to style it?

```
<div>
<img src=""/>
<img src=""/>
</div>
```

This of course give me images on the same line but with some spaces. Of course only when i write `<img src=""\>` on the same line it works. Display inlnine doesn't helps to me. Any clues?

Comment: Try float:left. Though you'll need to clearfix the containing div.

Comment: http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html do you mean that? :)

I try also a few diffrent ways and it doesn't works

Comment: Overflow is not neccesery it works anyway :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's recommended start with some css reset, like this:
[CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Then use:

```
img {
    float:left;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: The easiest way. I forget about that. Thanx :)